# Is it correct to say, "Additionem in prima, secunda, et tertia syllogismi"?

Tags: history, translation-check, philosophy-terms, logic

Is it correct to say, "*Additionem in prima, secunda, et tertia syllogismi*"? I'm trying my very best to say, "The addition of the first, second, and third syllogisms."

Comment: Can you explain a little more of your intended meaning in English?

Comment: I have a table of syllogisms wherein each is labeled by number, but I don't know how to refer, in Latin, to "the first, second, and third syllogisms".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that *syllogismus* is masculine, and to indicate anything over which you exercise an activity you have to use *in* + ablative, if I have correctly understand what you mean, the correctly translation could be:

> *additionem in primo, secundo, et tertio syllogismo*

which however means "the addition **over** the first, second, and third syllogism" (to add something to the first, second, and third syllogisms, which are different).

Otherwise you can use the genitive without praeposition:

> *additionem primi, secundi, et tertii syllogismi*

which more specifically means "the addition **of** the first, second, and third syllogisms" (three different syllogysms are summed)

The phrase *additionem in prima, secunda, et tertia syllogismi*, infer that something is elided (probably the word *pars*):

> *additionem in prima, secunda, et tertia (parte) syllogismi*

which means: "the addition **over** the first, second, and third **part** of the syllogisms" (to add something in the first, second and third part of the same syllogism).